# How to handle time-consuming command lines on startup files?

Tags: bash, startup

I have a command that I desire to run it automatically only once at the starting up. The solution I found is to put it on the startup file of login shell session, `~/.profile`. The problem is that this command is rather time consuming, which delays a lot the initialization.

How to solve it? I want to `rclone` data from a Google Drive.

Comment: Why would you put it in profile, instead of running it as a startup unit? Or is the intent that it prepares your shell? Could you actually tell us what the script does?

Comment: "instead of running it as a startup unit?", my friend, [I have no idea](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/234/765/b7e.jpg) what you mean.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "is the intent that it prepares your shell?" Answer: No; "Could you actually tell us what the script does?" Answer: Sure, it is a [rclone](https://rclone.org/) command that synchronizes my local files with Google Drive stuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe doesn't require or suggest doing this in your shell initialization, but simply as unit required for your user session to work.

If you want that to be done *before* you reach your graphical target or your multi-user boot target get reached, you just make sure your startup system has a startup script it calls.

Now, you don't say which startup system you're using, or even which operating system – but reading "bash", I suppose it's Linux with systemd.

This makes this pretty easy. Just write a so called *systemd unit file* that you then make a boot requirement. That's pretty elegant, as it could run as soon as your network is brought up, and while the other things in your system are initialized in parallel; since syncing files will mostly be bound by waiting for network data, this will basically put no extra load on your system, and the syncing is done as soon as you can log in.

A systemd unit file that'd do would look roughly like this:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Syncing stuff to and fro Google Drive

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rclone --options-to-rclone --whatevers
Requires=network.target
After=network.target
# The following only if not right to run rclone as root
User=yourusername
Group=yourgroupnametypicallysameasusername

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
# use WantedBy=graphical.target instead if you need that to be done
# only when the system's ready to log in graphically
```

put that as .service file in a systemd system service file directory, e.g., `/etc/systemd/system/rsync-googledrive.server`, and `sudo systemctl enable rsync-googledrive` will then make sure the service is started at boot.

You can also, instead, make it a user service, by putting it into `~/.config/systemd/user/`; remove the `User=` and `Group=` lines in that case, and replace the `WantedBy=` line by `WantedBy=default.target`.